# iPad air 2 screen rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, screen

I just got an iPad Air 2. I would like to lock the screen rotation but it doesn't have the rotation lock switch. I also checked this community and tried someone's answer, which was to go to control center. This didn't work because I didn't see  rotation lock control in control center.

Answer (score 4):

On an iPad Air 2, to access the screen rotation controls:

1. Turn on/unlock iPad
2. Swipe up from the bottom of the screen
3. Tap icon which shows padlock with rotating arrow around it - White is on, Grey is off.

Source: [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203121)

There has also been a noted issue on iOS 8 (pre-8.1) with the rotation lock. You may, if you haven't already, try updating to iOS v8.1+ should the above steps not work.

Answer (score 2):

iPad Air 2 with IOS 12.1.1, in landscape position, swipe down from upper right corner to access control center. Then you should see a padlock icon. Touch to turn off/on.